# Rails - how to query the database to obtain all types of products in a specific category

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have 3 models, Type, Category & Product. I am building an ecommerce platform and on the main products page I am able to list all of the many products of a particular category (Mens,Womens, Tshirts, Hats).

What I would like to do now is loop through all the product types tied to a specific category. The product types would be for the Mens category(Tanks, Tees, Shirts), and Womens category would have (Dresses, Tanks, Shirts), Hats would be (Flexfit, Trucker, Camper) and Hoodies would be (Pullover, Zipup).

A sample output would be
For Mens => Tanks, Tees, Shirts.

I am not sure if this would be a belongs to has many relationship between type and category, so the code in Type.rb might not be correct. I would like to know how to query the database to find all types of products in a category and also how to input them inside my seeds file.

Thanks!

Here is my code.

Category.rb

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :categorizations
 has_many :products, through: :categorizations
 has_many :types
end
```

Product.rb

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :options, dependent: :destroy
 has_many :images, dependent: :destroy

 has_many :categorizations
 has_many :categories, through: :categorizations

 has_many :types



 def image_url
  self.images.first.url
 end

 def has_image?
  self.images.exists?
 end

end
```

Type.rb

```
class Type < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :product
 belongs_to :category
end
```

categories_controller.rb

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController

def show
 @products = Product.includes(:categories).where('categories.name' => params[:name])
 ap @products

render :layout => 'application_categories'
end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the documentation and the actual code for Spree. The domain model is probably a lot more than what you are looking for but at least you'll understand what a full-blown e-commerce platform looks like for dealing with product taxonomies.  http://guides.spreecommerce.com/developer/products.html

Answer (score 0):

**Ancestry**

This sounds like a job for the [`Ancestry` gem](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry):

```
#app/models/product.rb
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :category
end

#app/models/category.rb
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :products
   has_ancestry
end
```

Here's how it works:

[image]

When you have a hierarchy setup in your database (through either the [`ancestry`](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry) or [`closure_tree`](https://github.com/mceachen/closure_tree) gems), your `objects` have a series of "methods" appended to them, which give you the ability to call things such as `object.children`

The importance of this will become apparent in a second

---

**Nesting**

You'll want to ensure you can filter your products by category:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :products, except: :show do
   collection do
      resources :categories, path: "" only: :show #-> domain.com/products/:id
   end
end
```

This will definitely conflict with your `products#show` action (ignore it for now). From this, you'll then be able to use the following:

```
<%= link_to "Hats", products_categories_path("hats") %>
```

This will route a request to the following controller:

```
#app/controllers/categories_controller.rb
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
   def show
      @category = Category.find params[:id]
   end
end

#app/views/categories/show.html.erb
<%= render partial: "category", locals: { category: @category } %>
<%= render partial: "category", collection: @category.children, as: :category if @category.has_children? %>

#app/views/categories/_category.html.erb
<%= category.products.each do |product| %>
   <%= link_to product.name, product %>
<% end %>
```

---

**Extensions**

This will give you the ability to call as many `categories` as you want in your views.

Admittedly, the structure I've outline above is somewhat constrained, but it's equally *very* important in giving you the scope & ability to show categories as part of a tree

If you need any more specifics, I'll be glad to give you some refactoring!